# Display the top 10 highest numbers out of my database table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to list the top highest 10 values in my MySQL table.

I am basically making a leader board and i need to top 10 highest numbers in my db.

Comment: So....what is the question, what DB are you running? I will tell you to look at `top` or `limit`  and debug your current issue. Too broad as is.

Comment: @chris85 i am running MySQL aka phpmyadmin

Comment: @AlexPlue, MySQL is not know as phpmyadmin FYI

Comment: What code have tried yet ? Share with us.

Comment: I have not tried any code @psyco im just new and got noone to help me. I cant find it in the internet or anything.

Answer (score 0):

Order DESC by the column you need. Limit 1,10 to get the first 10

Answer (score 0):

You could use `order by` and `limit` clauses:

```
SELECT   currency
FROM     players
ORDER BY currency DESC
LIMIT    10
```

Comment: Can you please type out the code as i should paste it? i currently have
'$SQL = $odb -> query("SELECT `currency` FROM `players`' im lost at the order by and the limit

@Mureinik

Comment: @AlexPlue changed my example to user your table and columns names

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `column_name` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `column_name` DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Hope this helps.